# Will a group view on my documents allow me to avoid the 5000 item limit

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a folder that has 3,500 documents.  Once I get beyond 5,000 documents I know the ALL view will not be available due to the 5000 view item threshold.  However, if I create a Group View called Summary that groups (meta data) on 2 columns I created  Month and Year will I have an issue or will I be ok ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At any point the view will not work if the items returned exceeds 5000.

You can make those metadata columns into the indexed columns.

Then use those columns to filter the data. The filter should be like that it won't return more than the threshold limit.

Not recommended approach is to change the resource throttling settings from central administration.